# Storing Geodata in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datamodel, geohashing

Are there any current extensions/functionalities for Cassandra to store and query efficiently geodata, e.g., by using geohashes?

What would you recommend to consider, when defining a data model for such an use case?

I found the following link, but the content of this article is more about specific queries.

Kind regards

Comment: What type of select query you want to execute ?

Comment: The use case is the following. There are on the one hand signal data with long and lat values, being stored in Cassandra and an external geodata base (not in Cassandra) with further meta data for each geoposition. Main task will be therefore a matching of the geopositions. Moreover, there will be checks, if the sequences of signal data are inside a specific polygon.

Comment: There is no built in support. But you can use solr or [cassandra lucene index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.10/doc/documentation.rst#geo-shape-search)

Comment: Thanks for the link.